# Are there configurations where accelerated charge radiation recoil is calculable analytically?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Are there any analytically solvable charge&field configurations, where, if we calculate $\vec r(t)$ of charge ignoring any recoil from radiation, we'll get (maybe slightly) different result from the case where the recoil is correctly included?